# Where to find constants like "MaxKeys" of 1000 for S3 or "VersionStage" of AWSCURRENT in AWSSDK for .NET

Tags: aws-sdk-net

AWS SDK docs state certain constants or enumerations like listing files in S3 is limited to 1000 maximum results or prescribe certain enumerated values like AWSCURRENT and AWSPENDING in Secrets Manager.

Where can I find constants or enumerations within the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to AWS support, they don't exist unfortunately.

Comment: There's MULTIPLE_OBJECT_DELETE_LIMIT but internal